# How to compile a libtorrent(rasterbar) code ?

Tags: boost, compilation, g++, libtorrent

I want to compile example (make_torrent) from [libtorrent official website](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/examples.html):

```
g++ create_torrent_file.cpp -o run -lboost_filesystem-mt
```

But I get this error:

```
create_torrent_file.cpp:(.text+0x158): undefined reference to
`libtorrent::file_storage::file_storage()'
```

I have libtorrent-rasterbar installed

```
ldconfig -v | grep libtorrent:
libtorrent-rasterbar.so.6 -> libtorrent-rasterbar.so.6.0.0
```

So how should I compile this source code?

Comment: Try adding `-llibtorrent-rasterbar` to the end of the `g++` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add libtorrent-rasterbar to the linker.  Try the following command:

```
g++ create_torrent_file.cpp -o run -ltorrent-rasterbar -lboost_filesystem-mt
```