# libtorrent-rasterbar7: g++ linker unable to find libtorrent/session.hpp

Tags: c++, g++, libtorrent-rasterbar

When compiling the libtorrent tutorial ['hello world'](http://libtorrent.org/tutorial.html) with:

`g++ main.cpp -o run -ltorrent-rasterbar -lboost_filesystem-mt -L /usr/lib/`

=> `fatal error: libtorrent/session.hpp: No such file or directory`

Despite having libtorrent-rasterbar7 installed (both `libtorrent-rasterbar.so.7` and `libtorrent-rasterbar.so.7.0.0` exist in `/usr/lib/`). Also I'm able to run a simple python script that imports and uses libtorrent without issues.

The g++ command I'm using is identical to the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5390438/1053362) for a similar issue with version 6 yet **still** having the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't installed the `libtorrent-rasterbar` header files. The
package you are missing is the `libtorrent-rasterbar` development
package. What it is called depends on your distro. (On Debian or Ubuntu
it is `libtorrent-rasterbar-dev`. On Fedora it is `libtorrent-rasterbar-devel`).

Whenever you want to write an application that links with a packaged library
you need to install not simply the runtime library but the associated development
package, which provides both the runtime library and its header files.

BTW, there is no need to pass `-L /usr/lib` to the linker as `/usr/lib` is one of the default linker search directories.