# How to compile a c++ code using libtorrent?

Tags: c++, compilation, libtorrent, libtorrent-rasterbar

I am testing the example code posted on the official libtorrent website (https://www.libtorrent.org/tutorial-ref.html). I pasted the code here:

```
#include <libtorrent/session.hpp>
#include <libtorrent/add_torrent_params.hpp>
#include <libtorrent/torrent_handle.hpp>
#include <libtorrent/magnet_uri.hpp>

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
        if (argc != 2) {
                fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <magnet-url>\n");
                return 1;
        }
        lt::session ses;

        lt::add_torrent_params atp = lt::parse_magnet_uri(argv[1]);
        atp.save_path = "."; // save in current dir
        lt::torrent_handle h = ses.add_torrent(atp);

        // ...
}
```

I have already installed the libtorrent:

```
ldconfig -v | grep libtorrent
libtorrent-rasterbar.so.9 -\> libtorrent-rasterbar.so.9.0.0
```

I used the following command to compile the code:

```
g++ main.cpp -o run -ltorrent-rasterbar -lboost_filesystem-mt
```

However, I got errors:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, const char\*\*)':
main.cpp:12:3: error: 'lt' has not been declared
lt::session ses;
```

I also saw another solution, but it does not resolve the issue I am facing: [How to compile a libtorrent(rasterbar) code ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390324/how-to-compile-a-libtorrentrasterbar-code)

Does anyone know what caused this failure?

Comment: You didn’t tell the compiler where to find the library or the includes.

Comment: You are not compiling your code. You have `char const* argv[])` but the error message oddly has `const char\*\*)':`. Are these  _verbatim exact_ whole all messages from the compiler? Did the compiler find includes?

Comment: What version of libtorrent did you download? libtorrent/config.hpp has `namespace lt = libtorrent;`, which is automatically included by other headers in your sample. It should just work. And it *does* work on my machine.

Comment: Hi @sweenish, thanks for the reply. Do you mean -I and -L flags used in the Makefile?

Comment: Hi @KamilCuk, thanks for the reply. I am pretty sure I am compiling the correct source code. However, I am not sure how to tell the compiler where to find includes.

Comment: `how to tell the compiler where to find includes` The error code you posted does not mention includes. Are include files not found? Please try `using lt = libtorrent;` on top of your file. I see the namespace is https://github.com/steeve/libtorrent/blob/master/include/libtorrent/session.hpp#L78

Comment: Hi @Botje, thanks for the reply. I installed the latest version.

Comment: @KamilCuk. Compiler did not complain about include files. `using lt = libtorrent;` did not work.
`main.cpp:6:12: error: 'libtorrent' does not name a type using lt = libtorrent;`

Comment: as I said earlier, version 2.0.8 ("the latest") already defines the `lt` shorthand namespace inside a file that is included by all other headers. And the 1.x range *also* defines this shorthand. So you are omitting a crucial bit of information and we don't know what it is. Voting to close as "cannot reproduce"